# SQL statement with 6 SELECTs in UNION returns only 2 rows

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql, union

I have a table of rows holding four different fields of numbers: people, debris, miles and bags.  All of these fields are 0 for every row right now because there is no data yet.  These rows also have two important fields called 'County', whose value is one of the counties of New York state, and 'Underwater', which is simply a 1/0 (yes/no) field. So they look something like this...

```
County      Underwater  People Debris Miles Bags
Richmond             0       0      0     0    0
Rockland             1       0      0     0    0
Nassau               0       0      0     0    0
Queens               1       0      0     0    0
Niagara              0       0      0     0    0
```

In order to group all of this together for a PHP page, I'm using a long SQL statement with lots of UNIONs and essentially separating the results by the counties in New York City, the ones from Long Island, and Upstate New York, and then two other queries for underwater and not underwater, then a grand total.  I figured a long statement used once would be more efficient than six separate queries to the same table, and it would save me some lines of code.  I was using test numbers prior to all the data being 0 and it worked fine.  Now that all the data is 0, the result set is a row of all 0's, then a row of NULLs, and nothing else.  Since I'm parsing the data using a foreach PHP loop, it's sort've screwing with my algorithm.  I've also noticed that if I change even just 1 row's data (even if it's only 1 field) to be non-zero, then I will get another row in my result set.

Can anyone explain this behavior and a solution or maybe offer an alternative?  I could go more in-depth if need be.

This is the statement in question by the way.  Standby for wall...

```
SELECT SUM( people ) AS people, SUM( debris ) AS debris, SUM( miles ) AS miles, SUM( bags ) AS bags 
FROM `table` 
WHERE county='The Bronx' OR county='Kings' OR county='New York' OR county='Queens' OR county='Richmond' 
UNION 
SELECT SUM( people ) AS people, SUM( debris ) AS debris, SUM( miles ) AS miles, SUM( bags ) AS bags 
FROM `table` 
WHERE county='Nassau' OR county='Suffolk' 
UNION 
SELECT SUM( people ) AS people, SUM( debris ) AS debris, SUM( miles ) AS miles, SUM( bags ) AS bags 
FROM `table` 
WHERE county='Albany' OR county='Allegany' OR county='Broome' OR county='Cattaraugus' OR county='Cayuga' OR county='Chautauqua' OR county='Chemung' OR county='Chenango' OR county='Clinton' OR county='Columbia' OR county='Cortland' OR county='Delaware' OR county='Dutchess' OR county='Erie' OR county='Essex' OR county='Franklin' OR county='Fulton' OR county='Genesee' OR county='Greene' OR county='Hamilton' OR county='Herkimer' OR county='Jefferson' OR county='Lewis' OR county='Livingston' OR county='Madison' OR county='Monroe' OR county='Montgomery' OR county='Niagara' OR county='Oneida' OR county='Onondaga' OR county='Ontario' OR county='Orange' OR county='Orleans' OR county='Oswego' OR county='Otsego' OR county='Putnam' OR county='Rensselaer' OR county='Rockland' OR county='Saratoga' OR county='Schenectady' OR county='Schoharie' OR county='Schuyler' OR county='Seneca' OR county='Steuben' OR county='StLawrence' OR county='Sullivan' OR county='Tioga' OR county='Tompkins' OR county='Ulster' OR county='Warren' OR county='Washington' OR county='Wayne' OR county='Westchester' OR county='Wyoming' OR county='Yates' 
UNION 
SELECT SUM( people ) AS people, SUM( debris ) AS debris, SUM( miles ) AS miles, SUM( bags ) AS bags 
FROM `table` 
WHERE underwater = '0' AND county != '' 
UNION 
SELECT SUM( people ) AS people, SUM( debris ) AS debris, SUM( miles ) AS miles, SUM( bags ) AS bags 
FROM `table` 
WHERE underwater = '1' AND county != '' 
UNION 
SELECT SUM( people ) AS people, SUM( debris ) AS debris, SUM( miles ) AS miles, SUM( bags ) AS bags 
FROM `table` 
WHERE county != '' AND fname != '' AND lname != ''
```

Comment: You're asking for help with a statement, but you haven't quoted the statement in your question.

Comment: Kinda wanted to avoid posting it since it's pretty big, but ok.

Comment: @matthias: have you never heard of the `WHERE contry IN ('Allegany', 'Broome', 'Cattaraugus', 'Cayuga', '…')` syntax?

Comment: I have not.  Thank you for that nugget of wisdom.  And for editing the code to show properly.  How did you do that, by the way?

Comment: @Mathias: To the right when you're asking/editing a question there's a box titled **How to Format**. Also a **[?]** link above the editing area with more information. And tooltips on the buttons above it. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.  The `UNION` operator will throw out duplicate rows between the two result sets, much like `SELECT DISTINCT` does for a single result set.  (Or select the county name too, since that will cause the result rows to contain non-identical data.)

---

To eliminate NULL rows from the query (which are the result of aggregate functions like `SUM()` over empty data sets) just do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    your query here
) AS x
WHERE x.people IS NOT NULL
```

Alternatively, change every occurrence of `SUM(x)` in your query to `COALESCE(SUM(x), 0)`.

Comment: This did it.  The only problem I have now is that one of the 6 rows returns all NULLs because, for that particular SELECT statement, there are no results (no rows meet the criteria 'Underwater' = 1).  Is there anyway I can have this default to a row of 0s instead of a row of NULLs?  Or would I have to test for NULL on the frontend and print out 0s?

Comment: @Mathias: Updated my answer to include a solution to that problem.

Comment: I added COALESCE to all my SUM(x) functions.  Changed all the NULLs to 0s and it makes for a good failsafe.  Thanks.